# starting WSO2 carbon with su

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, wso2

I did install the WSO2 Identity server on a Ubuntu 10.4 server and connected it to a MySQL database. Now I did create a user wso2user and gave this user full permission over the WSO2 folders. When I start the server with the following command:

```
#! /bin/sh
su wso2user -c '/opt/identitywso2/bin/wso2server.sh'
```

the server starts and I can log in, but the my command prompt stays in the shell with the last log message:

```
[2014-05-19 14:14:27,938]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent} -  Started thrift entitlement service at port:10500
[2014-05-19 14:14:43,534]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.SchemaBuilder} -  XACML policy schema loaded successfully.
```

What could be wrong? I want to start the serve without need to stay in the shell.

Thanks for any hints.
Lucas

Comment: You might want to start the product with osgi console to find out whether osgi bundles were resolved correctly. For that, start your server as `/opt/identitywso2/bin/wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole`. Then, when the server starts up, enter `ss` command in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script, based on WSO2 API Manager, but you can use to also for any other WSO2 product. Script is based on Suse EE SP3. Put this file in /etc/init.d and do a checkconfig.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/wso2
# init script for wso2.
#
# chkconfig: 2345 90 60
# description: wso2 indexer service
#
RETVAL=0

. /etc/rc.status

BAD_USER="This script should be run as root or as wso2 user. Exiting......."

cmd="/bin/sh -c"
if [ "$USER" != 'root' -a "$USER" != 'wso2' -a "$USER" != '' ]; then echo $BAD_USER && exit 1;fi
if [ "$USER" == 'root' -o "$USER" == '' ]; then cmd="su - wso2 -c";fi

wso2pid=`pidof java`

wso2_start() {
  echo Starting wso2...
  $cmd "/opt/wso2/am/bin/wso2server.sh --start"
}
wso2_stop() {
  echo Stopping wso2...
  $cmd "/opt/wso2/am/bin/wso2server.sh --stop"
  if [ -n "$wso2pid" ]
  then
    echo -n "Waiting for wso2 ($wso2pid)"
    while [[ ( -d /proc/$wso2pid ) ]]
    do
      echo -n "."
      sleep 1
    done
    echo "Stopped"
  fi
}
wso2_restart() {
  echo Restarting wso2...
  $cmd "/opt/wso2/am/bin/wso2server.sh --restart"
}
wso2_status() {
  echo -n "Status of wso2 is "
  if [ -n "$wso2pid" ]
  then echo "Running. ($wso2pid)"
  else echo "Stopped."
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  status)
    wso2_status
    ;;
  start)
    wso2_start
    ;;
  stop)
    wso2_stop
    ;;
  restart)
    wso2_restart
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: Hi marc,  thank you very much for the script. It did already help to change the command to wso2server.sh --start. But I will use the script in a later stage. Lucas